# Add Alt attribute to image served with php

Tags: php, tags, html

I am new to the forum and I hope to provide value..

Question that I have is that I am trying to add alt to a logo using php...

The website is wordpress and is pretty much customized by a different developer..

The php in questions is as follows:

```
    <div class="bd-layoutcolumn-20 bd-column" ><div class="bd-vertical-align-wrapper">
    <img class="bd-imagelink-3 bd-imagestyles   "  src="<?php echo theme_get_image_path
     ('images/b56392d722ada5890c6d2f29f1dbde4a_logo.jpg'); ?>">
```

Where would I insert the alt"" in that string?

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add it in...

```
  <div class="bd-layoutcolumn-20 bd-column" ><div class="bd-vertical-align-wrapper">
    <img alt ="my alt tag" class="bd-imagelink-3 bd-imagestyles   "  src="<?php echo theme_get_image_path
     ('images/b56392d722ada5890c6d2f29f1dbde4a_logo.jpg'); ?>">
```

if you're going to make it dynamic you'll need to add the php.  Something like this if you're in a loop:

```
  <div class="bd-layoutcolumn-20 bd-column" ><div class="bd-vertical-align-wrapper">
    <img alt ="<?php echo get_the_title();?>" class="bd-imagelink-3 bd-imagestyles   "  src="<?php echo theme_get_image_path
     ('images/b56392d722ada5890c6d2f29f1dbde4a_logo.jpg'); ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. This was the solutions that I needed!

Comment: can you Mark it as the correct answer please?

Comment: Hi Michael.  Would you mind marking the answer?  (check mark to the left of my answer) so we can have this question marked answered?